# Search products with manufacturer names

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I've been using the [Search API](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/performing-searches.html) to fetch the list of products that match a query, but I've seen that manufacturers are not returned as part of the

Answer (score 0):

login to admin navigate to store > product attributes then search for manufacturer click on it and navigate to Storefront Properties. check options here and enable where you want to display manufacturer attribute.

Please find attached screenshot.

[image]

Note: after done changes make sure you clear cache and do reindexing.